# MySql Optimization for Select only rows with Max Value on a Column from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an ecommerce scripts.

I have a table "commerce_product".

```
+--------------+---------+----------------------------+
| product_id   | title   | content                    |
+--------------+---------+----------------------------+
| 1            | ...     |  ...                       |
| 2            | ...     |  ...                       |
| 3            | ...     |  ...                       |
| 4            | ...     |  ...                       |
+--------------+---------+----------------------------+
```

I have a table "commerce_product_price_index". In this table I save all differents prices for each products.
The price depends on the customer_group, the currency, the country, the geozone, the customer and a date period.

Here a example of this table.

```
+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| id   | product_id   | customer_group_id  | currency_id  | country_id  | geozone_id  | user_id  |  time_from  |  time_to     |   min_price  |  max_price  |  final_min_price |  final_max_price |
+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1    | 1            |  0                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 300              | 300              |
| 2    | 1            |  1                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 250              | 250              |
| 3    | 1            |  2                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 200              | 200              |
| 4    | 1            |  3                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 100              | 100              |
+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

In this example I have product with 4 differents prices.

First I do a select to calculate a score for each price.

```
SELECT 
    IF (1480090146 >= `time_from` AND 1480090146 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) + 
    IF (`customer_group_id` = 3, 2, 0) + 
    IF (`geozone_id` = 2, 4, 0) + 
    IF (`country_id` = 73, 8, 0) + 
    IF (`currency_id` = 1, 16, 0)+ 
    IF (`user_id` = 2352, 32, 0) AS score,
    `cppi`.* 
    FROM 
        `commerce_product_price_index_2` AS `cppi` 
    WHERE 
        (geozone_id IN('2', 0)) 
        AND (country_id IN('73', 0)) 
        AND (currency_id IN('1', 0)) 
        AND (customer_group_id IN('3', 0)) 
        AND (user_id IN('2352', 0)) 
        AND (cppi.time_from <= 1480090146) 
        AND (cppi.time_to >= 1480090146) 
    ORDER BY `score` desc
```

I have a 2 results with the new column score

```
+--------+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| score  | id   | product_id   | customer_group_id  | currency_id  | country_id  | geozone_id  | user_id  |  time_from  |  time_to     |   min_price  |  max_price  |  final_min_price |  final_max_price |
+--------+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| 3      | 1    | 1            |  0                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 300              | 300              |
| 1      | 2    | 1            |  1                 | 0            | 0           | 0           | 0        | 1479942000  | 1480460400   | 500          | 500         | 250              | 250              |
+--------+------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

And in this result I select the max score to get the good price.

```
SELECT 
    `cppi2`.*, 
    MAX(score) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `cppi`.*, 
        IF (1480090146 >= `time_from` AND 1480090146 <= `time_to`, 1, 0) + 
        IF (`customer_group_id` = 3, 2, 0) + 
        IF (`geozone_id` = 2, 4, 0) + 
        IF (`country_id` = 73, 8, 0) + 
        IF (`currency_id` = 1, 16, 0)+ 
        IF (`user_id` = 2352, 32, 0) AS score 
        FROM 
            `commerce_product_price_index` AS `cppi` 
        WHERE 
            (geozone_id IN('2', 0)) 
            AND (country_id IN('73', 0)) 
            AND (currency_id IN('1', 0)) 
            AND (customer_group_id IN('3', 0)) 
            AND (user_id IN('2352', 0)) 
            AND (cppi.time_from <= 1480090146) 
            AND (cppi.time_to >= 1480090146) 
        ORDER BY `score` desc   

    ) AS `cppi2` 
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

And after I select my product table and I do a join with this request.

My question is: is it the good way to make that?

My product table has 13000 rows.
My price index table has 50000 rows.

Do you have a best solution?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can remove the `time_from` and `time_to` piece from the score calculation since this is part of the WHERE clause.

There is no need to `ORDER BY score` - `MAX(score)` will take care of that.

You should consider selecting only the columns you need rather than `SELECT cppi.*`

Your solution seems reasonable to me. Other solutions include calculating the score in code (or just preferring a certain price index using an if/else/case statement to check for user_id, customer_group_id, etc. in turn), rather than using mysql.

I tried to come up with a solution that used calculated boolean flags for whether attributes match and then ordering by them, but I couldn't get it to work with `GROUP BY product_id`. There might be a solution there but I don't think it would be any faster.

Comment: thks for your comment.
I wonder if it better to create a tempory table?